# How can I Get Min(time) and Max(time) per date

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Hi I am new to PHPmyadmin using xampp with no background to MYSQL. As I am enjoy studying how this works, a thought came into my head that won't let me sleep for a week now since I can't seem to figure out how to fetch report with the output I expect using MIN(time) and MAX(time) per date in "one column".

```
UserID  Name       Date        Time 
103     Pikachu     7/1/2018    11:01:16 PM
103     Pikachu     7/1/2018    11:01:20 PM 
103     Pikachu     7/1/2018    11:02:01 PM
204     Bulbasaur   7/1/2018    11:15:35 PM
103     Pikachu     7/1/2018    9:02:16  AM
103     Pikachu     7/1/2018    9:02:16  AM
204     Bulbasaur   7/1/2018    9:25:35  AM
204     Bulbasaur   7/2/2018    12:05:15 AM
204     Pikachu     7/2/2018    12:09:35 AM
```

Expected Output:

```
UserID  Name       Date        Time
103     Pikachu     7/1/2018    11:01:16 PM
103     Pikachu     7/1/2018    9:02:16  AM
204     Bulbasaur   7/1/2018    11:15:35 PM
204     Bulbasaur   7/1/2018    9:25:55  AM
204     Bulbasaur   7/2/2018    12:05:12 AM
204     Bulbasaur   7/2/2018    NULL
103     Pikachu     7/2/2018    12:09:35 AM
103     Pikachu     7/2/2018    NULL
```

Please, any help will be appreciated

Comment: just for you to know. PHPmyadmin is just a tool to run queries against a mysql database. It's a visual tool so there are some shortcuts to "click a button" instead of writing a query but it is just a matter of mysql queries. So your question should be "how can i do this in mysql"?

Comment: Thanks, for that. I'll change the title now to avoid confusion as well. Also, do you have an idea on how I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

agreed to @Mureinik  to use group by  but i think user_id and name also need to include in group by and use union all to combine both result

```
select distinct UserID,Name, date,Time from
 (
    SELECT  UserID,Name, date, MIN(time) as Time
    FROM     mytable
    GROUP BY date,UserID,Name
    union all

    SELECT  UserID,Name, date, MAX(time) as Time
    FROM     mytable
    GROUP BY date,UserID,Name
) as T
```

Comment: @Yhone Dominic Does it help?

Comment: Wow this is exactly what I AM LOOKING FOR! Thank you So much!! @Zaynul Abadin Tuhin

Comment: Hi @Zaynul may I also know how I can get the ones past 12AM as the max(time) <pre>204     Bulbasaur   7/1/2018    9:25:55  AM
204     Bulbasaur   7/2/2018    12:05:12 AM </pre>

Comment: you can use case when for checking as its past 12AM or not